# VueJS: call a custom filter on click

Tags: vue.js

I have this filter:

```
Vue.filter('limit', function (value, amount) {
   return value.filter(function(val, index, arr){
     return index < amount;      
   });
});
```

Which I'm using like this:

```
<div v-for="movimiento in movimientos | limit 7" class="c-movimientos-tabla__block">
```

How can I change the limit number on click in any button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `upperLimit` property to your Vue instance initially set the `7`:

```
data() {
  return {
    upperLimit: 7,
  }
}
```

Then, make a computed property `filteredMovimientos`, which is the initial `movimientos` with the `limit` filter passing in a value of your new `upperLimit` data property:

```
computed: {
  filteredMovimientos() {
    return Vue.filter('limit')(this.movimientos, this.upperLimit);
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, reference the `filteredMovimientos` in the `v-for` loop instead, and add a click handler to update the value of the `upperLimit` data property:

```
<div v-for="movimiento in filteredMovimientos" @click="upperLimit = 10">
```

---

Alternatively, you could still specify the filter in the `v-for` and pass `upperLimit` as the argument there as well:

```
<div v-for="movimiento in movimientos | limit upperLimit" @click="upperLimit = 10">
```

**Note:** filtering on `v-for` is not supported in Vue v2, so if you ever wanted to migrate your code to that version, you would need to use a computed property.

Comment: if i use a button outside of v-for, can i use like that @click ?

Comment: yep, you can affect `upperLimit` anywhere within the scope of the Vue instance's template